# Show conferences when "Country" is clicked is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I have a modal that has some cities. If the user clicks in a city then in the #conferences div it appears the conferences that have in the column "city" that clicked city. This is working fine.

My doubt is how to, if the user clicks in Country, instead of a city, how to get all conferences, independently of the city because if the user click in Country the results can be of any city.

Do you know how to achieve that?

With value attribute like "" "`<a  value="">Country</a>`" when "Country" is clicked in the console appears:
" `{message: "", "exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…}" in file "/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php`".

ConferenceController method to get the conferences of the clicked city:

```
  public function getConferencesOfCity($slug)
    {

        $conferences = Conference::whereCity($slug)->get();


        return response()->json($conferences);
    }
```

Modal where the city links appears:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="modal-list row">
            <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <a  class=""  name="" id="" value="">Country</a>
            </li>
            @foreach($cities as $city)
                <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <a  class=""  name="city" id="{{$city}}">{{$city}}</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('conferences/where/city/{slug}','ConferenceController@getConferencesOfCity')->name('city.conferences');
```

jQuery ajax request:

```
$("a[name='city']").on('click', function(){

    $('#showCities').html($(this).text());
    var city = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('city.conferences',null) }}/' + city,
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result)

            $('#conferences').empty();
            var newConferences='';
            var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";
            $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
                $('#modal2').modal('hide');
                var url = placeholder.replace(1, conference.id).replace('demo-slug', conference.slug);

                newConferences += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">\n' +
   ' <h5 class="card-title">'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
      <p class="card-text font-size-sm">'+conference.city+'</p>\n' +
                '                    </div>\n';
            });
            $('#conferences').html(newConferences);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error.status)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `var placeholder` How to binding route url of Laravel function (server-side only) in jQuery. I think you have confused? jQuery will be work when the webpage has been rendered. Please check.

Comment: But it works, when a city in the modal is clicked, in the #conferences div it appears the conferences that have the column "city" equal to the clicked city. But it's not working when "Country" is clicked, when "Country" is clicked it should get the conferences of all cities.

Comment: You can check the URL on Network tab when the button has been clicked.

Comment: When "Country" is clicked the url is "http://proj.test/conferences/where/city" and it shows the "NotFoundHttpException" error. When a citiy is clicked, for example "Newcastle", the url is "http://proj.test/conferences/where/city/Newcastle".

Comment: Ahhh, the problem is routing does not exist on Laravel side. It's actually different to your defined route above. Just add more route for that case.